# Was Brett Gardner first MLB player to hit consecutive walk-off home run and lead off home run?

Tags: trivia, mlb

Brett Gardner hit a walk off home run against Tampa and the next game lead of with a home run.  Was this ever done before by any other player?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, it has been done by many players though not sure how many times in MLB history. And [Brett Gardner became the third player in Yankees history](http://www.espn.com/blog/elias-says/post/_/id/1277/elias-says-july-29-2017) to hit a home run leading off the game, the game after hitting a walk-off home run. Hall of Famer Joe Gordon did it in 1940 and Roberto Kelly in 1990.